# How to get values from two tables by joins?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I have two tables `table1` and `table2`:

**table1:**

```
id (primary key)
name
email
category1 (foreign key to table2.id)
category2 (foreign key to table2.id)
category3 (foreign key to table2.id)
```

**table2: (categories)**

```
id (primary key)
name
```

I want to write a select query to get the category names instead of the categoryId.

Comment: Could you give some data of how your tables looks like? Your Opening question is a bit confusing.

Comment: where do you get the CategoryName from? I can't find it in the table2 neither!

Comment: table1  fields : id , name , email , category1(id in categorys table) .......

Comment: table2 fields : id , name.....

Comment: i want a query to get category names insted of id's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 3 joins with the same table:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.email, c1.cat_name cn1, c2.cat_name cn2, c3.cat_name cn3 
FROM test t LEFT JOIN cat c1 ON (cat1=c1.id)
            LEFT JOIN cat c2 ON (cat2=c2.id)
            LEFT JOIN cat c3 ON (cat3=c3.id)
```

Tested with Mysql: [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/daab8/2)

Comment: but, in table1 if cat1,cat2,cat3(ids) anyone is empty.......i am not getting the entire row......can you please help me

Comment: @TatisettiRamanjaneyulu You have to make a left join, ill edit my answer.

Comment: @TatisettiRamanjaneyulu Happy for that :) plz consider to select answer

Comment: some body commented on my comment "Instead of saying thanks you should consider marking one of the answers as accepted. That is how Stack Overflow works best". i want to accept your answer. how to do that?

Comment: @TatisettiRamanjaneyulu : To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in,please check the SOF [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to join the category table once for every category (and use aliases to differentiate them):

```
select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.name, 
    t1.email, 
    t2_cat1.name,
    t2_cat2.name,
    t2_cat3.name
from 
    table1 t1 
join 
    table2 as t2_cat1 on t1.category1 = t2_cat1.id
join 
    table2 as t2_cat2 on t1.category2 = t2_cat2.id
join 
    table2 as t2_cat3 on t1.category3 = t2_cat3.id
```

If any of the table1.category* columns can be null you might want to use a left join instead to make sure data is returned for the other columns.

Comment: @TatisettiRamanjaneyulu Instead of saying thanks you should consider marking one of the answers as accepted. That is how Stack Overflow works best.

Answer (score 0):

Confusing question..

Assuming that the table 2 contains the CategoryName and that the table 1 contains the category id for category 1, 2 and 3, you can proceed as;

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.CategoryName, t3.CategoryName, t4.CategoryName
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.category1Id = t2.id
JOIN table2 t3
ON t1.category1Id = t3.id
JOIN table2 t4
ON t1.category1Id = t4.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.name,
       T1.email,
       C1.name AS CategoryName1,
       C2.name AS CategoryName2,
       C3.name AS CategoryName3
FROM table2 T1 
INNER JOIN table2 C1 
ON T1.category1 = C1.id
INNER JOIN table2 C2 
ON T1.category2 = C2.id
INNER JOIN table2 C3 
ON T1.category3 = C3.id
```